# Laravel - Elasticsearch ClientBuilder Not found

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch, composer-php

I am using Laravel 5.7 and `Elasticsearch/elasticsearch ^6.1`
I installed elasticsearch via composer and my class is as follows

```
use Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder;

trait Elasticable {
    public abstract function getType();
    public abstract function getIndex();
    public function getClient() {
        $elastic= Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()           
        ->setHosts(\Config::get('app.esserver'))      
        ->build();            
        return $elastic;
    }
```

However, I keep getting

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class
>   'App\Traits\Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder' not found in file

Somehow Laravel / PHP is not recognizing Elasticsearch namespace or some autoload issue
I have tried `composer dump-autoload` and that does not help

Comment: If you are using class at the top then you can directly refer it like `$elastic= ClientBuilder::create()`. Also just do `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: I feel so dumb! That was it! Thanks Mihir

Comment: Glad it worked  :)